# Как обойти ограничение post запросов на wordpress

Tags: python, wordpress, aiohttp

Я обновляю alt в изображениях в WordPress через свой скрипт на python. Изображений много, но на сайте стоит ограничение в 60 запросов в минуту, у меня на каждую картинку уходит по 2 запроса. После обработки 30 изображений все повисает и падает таймаут.
aiohttp-retry в этом случае не помогает даже с большими значениями. я пробовал вот так c таймаутом на 2 минуты:

```
 retry_options = ExponentialRetry(attempts=5, max_timeout=121)
        self.session = aiohttp.ClientSession(cookie_jar=self.cookie_jar)
        self.client = RetryClient(raise_for_status=False, retry_options=retry_options, client_session=self.session)
```

Но все равно после 30 постов падает всё. Что мне сделать, чтобы обойти это ограничение? У меня есть базовый доступ к админке, однако я не могу менять исходники кода, потому что они на FTP.

Comment: Это ограничение (60 запросов в минуту) к WordPress не имеет отношения. А вообще, надо делать вещи правильно. Скрипт создавать на PHP и запускать внутри WordPress. Или отправить запрос в базу.

Comment: А к чему имеет отношение? Я встречался с таким только на WordPress.
Я не прошу указывать мне какой язык использовать. Я не пишу на PHP.

Comment: К веб-серверу. В ядре WordPress нет какого-либо кода, который способен ограничивать число запросов к сайту. Да и в других CMS тоже. Такие ограничения делают на сервере.

Comment: Ну, как писал ранее - у меня нет доступа к серверу. Работодатель думает что я делаю все вручную. Но мне надо обойти это ограничение без ручного перезапуска скрипта

Comment: Во первых падение при запросах - проблема сервера, а не ВП, во вторых - задачу нужно решать через https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/. И вообще.. для решения этой задач (обновления альтов) есть готовые *правильные* решения. Не зачем костылить, да на чужеродных ЯП.